# Mongoose sort by ref counter

Tags: mongoose

I have poll & votes and I want to sort the top polls (the polls with the most votes).
This is my Schema:

```
pollSchema = Schema ({
    ...
};

voteSchema = Schema ({
    ...
    poll: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Poll" },
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
};
```

So basically each vote points to the poll it belongs to but not the other way around (To keep a single "source of truth").
(The reason I'm not referencing / keeping as a sub document the votes under polls, is because the vote should also reference the voter).

I'm struggling to find an easy way to sort all the polls by how much votes point to them (which basically saying sort polls by their num of votes).

Ofcourse there's the hard-work way (pseudo code):

```
- find all polls (Poll.find({}))
- count all votes to each poll and keeping it in a counter on each poll object (Vote.count({ poll: polls[i].id }))
- sort the polls like a regular javascript array
```

This should work ofcourse, but I'm looking for a better way if one's exists.
Kind of a newb to mongoose, so I might have miss something reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you wish to return number of votes that each pool received?

To achieve this, you can use Mongo aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ and then translate this into Moongose.

In your case, your code would look like:

```
Vote.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$poll", "votes": {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {"votes": -1}},
    {$lookup: {from: "polls", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "pollObject"}} //from is the name of table in database
])
```

This will return your array, where **_id** will represent your Poll and **votes** will represent number of votes received. The array will be sorted by number of votes descending. Note that **$lookup** returns an array, so you need to extract it.

Comment: Close. Is there a way to get the full poll object instead of just its' id? If not this is still extremely helpful so thanks!

Comment: If you are using newer version of a Mongo e.g 3.2 there is a way. See update answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. How could I also filter the polls? I mean as I would do regulary `polls.find({title: 'bla'})`,  Will piping `find` to the code you gave should work?

Comment: No just piping won't work, but you can use `{$match: {"title": "bla"}}` after lookup. This will work in the same manner as find. Or if you want to search in the populated field e.g pollObject, than you can search as `{$match: {"pollObject.0.title": "bla"}}`

Comment: After some tests I've found out that this works great except for one case: If a poll has no votes at all, it's missing from the query results. It makes sense I guess, since I'm aggregating the votes. Is there a way to "fix" this?

Comment: Nope, it will only show the polls that have votes. For others you will need to make a additional query.